# Java MDB - How to keep track of number of messages processed

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, jms, java-ee-6

I have an MDB that processes different types of messages (Object Messages). I want to keep a track of the number of messages received by the MDB and as well as keep count of the type of the messages received.

Although my MDB is distributed across multiple JVMs, I am fine keeping track of the count at individual JVM.

Using static variables is discouraged in EJB, so other alternatives do we have?

Comment: Isn't that the job of the message broker? One idea that comes to mind is to use persistent messages.

Comment: Is database any good option to store this data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea:

A `@Singleton` EJB comes to mind. I would call it `Statistics` and keep all kinds of statistics there. Each time a `Xxx` event, that requires statistics, occurs, a `addToXxxCount()` method could be called. The actual count is available from the corresponding  `getXxxCount()`. It would require read locks on `getXxxCount()` methods and write locks on `addToXxxCount()` (see concurrency for singleton EJBs). Alternatively, you can synchronize yourself.

The variable that actually keeps track of the count (`int` or `long`) is non-static and the container guarantees the EJB is intantiated only once. And you get a central point of reference for all your statistics.

Comment: You don't need a lock or synchronization for counters: use an `AtomicInteger` or `AtomicLong` with method `incrementAndGet`() to add a count, and use `get()` to get a count.

Comment: Yes, that's an option for the "synchronize yourself" part.